# How to setup (Passive) FTP server in VMware Player Guest VM

Tags: ftp, vmware, nat

I want to bring up an FTP server within my Linux Guest VM. I already have it setup and running within the VM but I run into issue with my VMWare Player (running on Windows 10).

I forwarded TCP 21 from host to guest. When I try to initiate FTP from client, it tries to switch to another port for data which is not the initial Port 21. Since the server port is randomly chosen during runtime, I cannot forward it. What can I do to make it work?

Comment: Change the networking in the Guest from NAT (default) to Bridged. That will give you an IP on your router.

Comment: That's not feasible for me. My Guest VM will not be able to obtain an IP in that network.

Comment: Strange - no reason why not. It will get an IP on the same subnet as your Host machine.

Comment: Naturally in passive mode the server needs to receive inbound connections on the data port range, in active mode it would be the client. So either you need to open/forward the whole passive mode port range, or switch to active mode and do that client side. Or you switch to SFTP on only port 22 ;).

Comment: And that would require a bridged connection in the Guest to set this up.